# app_code folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, app-code

Normally I only copy the dll files in the bin folder to update the website, when changing the codebehind.

I have made a change to a code file located in the app_code folder.

I have published the site and updated the bin folder with a lot of app_webxxx.dll files.

Now I get a parser error: Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_syn42ext

Is it possible to only update the dll files or do I need to update all aspx files everytime I make a change to get the website running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it as well, you need to update web pages as well, because if you will see when you publish the webpages in aspx page, on header tag, the reference of cs file upgrades itself.
So whenever you will publish there will be some random giud generated and will appended to file name, basically it reference to the name space.

So you will need to update web pages as well.